# Simple neural network with feedbacks in state-space form

Tags: dynamic, neural-networks, control-systems, modeling

Having studied more or less in detail the mechanisms of working with the state-space that Mathematica provides us with, I asked myself: can these tools be applied to neural networks?
This article helped formulate the problem:

[On neural networks in identification and control of dynamic systems](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930021849.pdf)

There, in paragraph 3.2. on page 8, it shows what a neural network would look like in a state-space.

It is natural to assume that this will be a discrete state-space with the corresponding matrices A, B, C, D. But, how they should be formed, it is not clear ...

Thus, we need to connect all the elements into one system ("SystemModelMerge"?) maybe, get the state-space and convert from discrete to continuous form. I want to know what more experienced Mathematica users think and experiment with it.

Structure of neural network:
[image]

Comment: Arn’t deep nn’s already a system with feedback?

Comment: You mean, is this system not already represented in the state-space? If not, then clarify the question.

Comment: I’ll make a clarification, just in case. This is a feedback system. I am wondering how to represent it in the state space using Mathematics, i.e. get the matrices A, B, C and D. And convert to a continuous system.